# Visual Studio 2015 popup on debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I was wondering if someone could tell me what this thing is in the screenshot? It just appeared after the update and I want to get rid of it as it blocks some of my buttons when I'm debugging.

I can collapse it but I would rather get rid of it and I have no idea what it is called, so I cant look through the tool bar to disable it.

[image: Screenshot of popup]

Comment: it's a WPF layout helper (think developer tools in Chrome/Firefox/IE/...) - just hit the wide `=` beneath and it should collapse quite a bit

Comment: it's called **In-App menu** and it seems that you can turn this off if you hit the *live visual tree* button (there) and disable the menu from there ([see the release notes here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx))

Comment: @Carsten Yeah thanks for that, its gone now, I don't know where it came from I have not touched the live visual tree at all.

Comment: I think it appears by default now - I could not find the settings either but it does not bother me to much

Comment: New feature in VS2015 Update 2, gives you live access to the XAML visual tree.  The boss override switch is Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML.